# How to inject data into custom type field for ngx-formly?

Tags: angular, forms, ngx-formly

my question is so simple: is it possible to inject data inside custom type field in a form created using ngx-formly?
I'm working on a Angular project (Angular 14) and I would like to create a select with custom behavior, so I write something like this in the appModule

```
FormlyModule.forRoot({
        types: [
            {
                name: 'risorseAutocomplete',
                component: AutocompleteTypeComponent,
                wrappers: ['form-field'],
            },
        ]
    })
```

Inside component AutocompleteTypeComponent I'll write code for template and for some logic in file .ts, but I would like to know if is possible to pass data (the options of the select ,in this specific example) from the file in which I create the form with object FormlyFieldConfig:

```
fields: FormlyFieldConfig[] = [
    {
        fieldGroupClassName: 'display-flex-2',
        fieldGroup: [
            {
                key: 'Autocomplete',
                type: 'risorseAutocomplete',
                props: {
                    required: true,
                    label: 'Autocomplete',
                    placeholder: 'Placeholder'
                }
            },
            {
                key: 'Datepicker',
                type: 'datepicker',
                className: 'width-20',
                props: {
                    label: 'Datepicker',
                    placeholder: 'Placeholder',
                    description: 'Description datepicker',
                    required: true,
                },
                parsers: [toDateParser]
            }
        ]
    }
];
```

If is this possible, how can I use it inside my custom component AutocompleteTypeComponent?
Thank you very much